# How to Select GeneratedColumn in Blazor Ant Design Table

Tags: blazor, ant-design-blazor

I don't know how can I select generated Table in Blazor Ant Design Table.

```
<TabPane Tab="BasicInfo" Key="1">
        <Table TItem="UserInfo" DataSource="@userDataSet" RowClassName="@(_=>"editable-row")">
            <GenerateColumns Range="0.." Definitions=definitions  />
```

This is my Table.

For example, I can Create new Column and can set that Column

```
<PropertyColumn Width="30%" Property="c=>c.Exp">
                    @if (!editCache[data.UserID].edit)
                    {
                        <Input Type="text" @bind-Value="data.Exp" OnBlur="()=>stopEdit(data.UserID)" AutoFocus />
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <div class="editable-cell-value-wrap" style="padding-right:24px" @onclick="()=>startEdit(data.UserID)">
                            @data.Exp
                        </div>
                    }
                </PropertyColumn>
```

But I Can't do this with GenerateColumns....

Help me Please

Already said at "What are the details of your problem?" Section